# Objects inside the stacklayout with a tap listener

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I want to add a tap listener to a StackLayout, but then I want all the objects inside the stack to share the same listener.

Over android could be *duplicateParentState* property on view tag, How could be for Xamarin forms?

Comment: Subscribe each your control including stack layout to the same event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is something quite the same in Forms. Instead, would you be able to use the `InputTransparent` property to work out a similar experience?

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.InputTransparent/

Otherwise, you could add the gesture recognizer to each child of the StackLayout.

Comment: Seems `InputTransparent` is not working. Still clicking on the label but not triggering the event. I had to add a gesture to each child.